# How to insert a new line every entry in a dictionary?

Tags: python, oop

```
def __repr__(self):
    'shows all city attributes'
    return str(self.__dict__).strip('{}').replace("'", "")
```

I have this in my class which returns:

```
    name: Jerusalem, center: (31, 35), central_station: (19.7, 25.22), num_residents: 900000, num_neighborhoods: 58
```

How can I change it to be (every detail in a new line):

```
    name: Jerusalem
    center:(9, 20)
        ...
        ...
```

and actually I have another question- is there a better way to do this list?

Comment: You can use `split(",")` method to split the string on commas then with the resulting list you can print the elements as you wish (on new line as you want).

Comment: Looks like you're probably after `return '\n'.join(f'{k}: {v}' for k, v in vars(self).items() if not k.startswith('_'))`....

Comment: You should edit the title. From the question, it looks as if you want a line break after each key-value pair - which is very different from a line break after "every 2 characters".

Comment: better rebuild the string for the dictionary by iterating on it as Jon noted

Comment: @jon-  I do have startswith('_')  and I changed the title. thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could iterate through the definitions, and apply a format to each item, like so...

```
class Foo:
    def __repr__(self):
        '''shows all city attributes'''
        line_format = '%s : %s'
        return "\n".join([line_format % (key, str(value)) for key, value in self.__dict__.items()])
```

and the usage would look like this...

```
a = Foo()
a.a = "Hello"
a.b = "World"
a.c = (1, 2, 3)
print(a)
```

> ```
> a : Hello
> b : World
> c : (1, 2, 3)
> ```

Now, if you want to change the format of your presentation, you can just change your `line_format` to something like `"%s -> %s"` or some other way of presenting the data.